# CodeIgniter Check If Logged In

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to perform a simple check whether a user is logged in or not (based on the session) and redirect him somewhere in case he isn't . This check needs to be done in all my controllers . Where do I put this check ? I know I can put it in all my controllers but that's repeating code . 
I know I can create a base controller with the check in it's constructor , let all my other controllers inherit from it so they inherit the check . 
Any other elegant solution for this ?

Comment: Putting it in your base controller is the way to do it.

Comment: 100% Agreed - base controller all day, as you continue to build your application you'll need more things in your base controller as well most likely

Comment: Base controller is a good solution, but be aware that you can also put the check into a hook that's executed before the controller is instantiated. In some cases this might be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make a controller extending CI_Controller with the check in the constructor like you said, and then have your various other auth'd controllers extend that one.

Comment: If you whole application is set behind authentication, Hippocrates is correct. If you have frontend and backend, create Admin_Controller with authentication check in the constructor, and extend all other backend Controllers from Admin_Controller. Frontend controllers are to be extended from the base CI_Controller.